# PyTorch - Receiving 0 Filled List from Prediction

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

ISSUE:

```
EXPECTED:tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
         0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
         0., 0., 1., 1.]], dtype=torch.float64)
ACTUAL:tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], device='cuda:0')
```

---

I'm building my own dataloader where I have a list of images, and each image has 40 attributes, with each attribute being a 0 or 1.
EG: index 1 might represent "Attractive", and index 2 might represent "Big Nose"

I am trying to send in a list of these numbers alongside each number with each index in that list corresponding to an attribute, and with a 0 or 1 in relation to that image.

My issue is that when training, the predicted values are all 0.

---

Get item in the dataloader, sends in the image alongside a list of numbers called 'attributes'

```
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()


        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,
                                self.malefemale_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = read_image(img_name)
        

        attributes = self.malefemale_frame.iloc[idx, 2:]
        attributes = [float(i) for i in attributes]
        attributes = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(attributes))
        #print(attributes)
        return image.float(), attributes
```

Batch size used here

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import os
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

batch_size = 8

trainset = MaleFemaleDataset(csv_file='attribute-files/CelebAMask-HQ-attribute-anno.txt', root_dir='CelebA-HQ-img//',transform=transform,train=True)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

testset = MaleFemaleDataset(csv_file='attribute-files/CelebAMask-HQ-attribute-anno.txt', root_dir='CelebA-HQ-img//',transform=transform,train=False)

testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=0)

print("Training/Testing sets initialized")
```

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

Training Loop

```
for epoch in range(1):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data
        inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
        #print(data[1])
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(inputs.to(device))
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward(gradient=torch.ones_like(loss))
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 100 == 99:    # print every 100 mini-batches
            print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 100:.3f}')
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

It doesn't get much better than 30...

```
[1,   100] loss: 33.356
[1,   200] loss: 36.982
[1,   300] loss: 36.495
[1,   400] loss: 33.763
...etc
```

Testing Loop

```
correct, total = 0, 0
with torch.no_grad():

# Iterate over the test data and generate predictions
    for i, data in enumerate(testloader, 0):

      # Get inputs
        inputs, targets = data

      # Generate outputs
        outputs = net(inputs.to(device))

        # Set total and correct
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 0)
        total += targets.size(0)
        print("EXPECTED:"+ str(targets))
        print("ACTUAL:"+ str(predicted.tolist()))
        #for predict in predicted:
        #    print(predict.item())
        correct += (predicted == targets).sum().item()

    # Print accuracy
    print('Accuracy: %d %%' % (100 * correct / total))
```

Final Output

```
EXPECTED:tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
         0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
         0., 0., 1., 1.]], dtype=torch.float64)
ACTUAL:tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], device='cuda:0')
```

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. only use tags for relevant technologies. I removed the OpenCV tag.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by modifying my testing loop. I removed the torch.max() function, and simply returned the values I got from the net.

```
correctAttributes = 0
threshold = .5
with torch.no_grad():

for i, data in enumerate(testloader, 0):

    # Get inputs
    inputs, targets = data

    # Generate outputs
    outputs = net(inputs.to(device))
    
    #Check predictions
    for predictedAttributes, targetAttributes in zip(outputs.tolist(), targets.tolist()):
        for predictedAttribute, targetAttribute in zip(predictedAttributes, targetAttributes):
            if predictedAttribute > threshold and targetAttribute > threshold:
                correctAttributes+=1
            elif predictedAttribute < threshold and targetAttribute < threshold:
                correctAttributes+=1
            total+=1

# Print accuracy
print('Accuracy: %d %%' % (100 * correctAttributes / total))
```